# Pyglet 1.2alpha1 not working on Python 3.3.0

Tags: python-3.x, pyglet

I can't use Pyglet 1.2alpha1 (which should be able to run under Py3) from Python 3.

I followed the instructions and installed it correctly, yet it doesn't run on Py3, but I know I installed everything right because I can use it from Python 2.7.

Every time I try to import piglet using the interpreter, I get this error:

```
>>> import pyglet

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "./pyglet/__init__.py", line 276
    print '[%d] %s%s %s' % (thread, indent, name, location)
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Reading the errore message it's quite obvious that the error is in the print being written in Python 2 style (`print foo` instead of `print(foo)`).

So my question is: is it real that one can run pyglet under Python 3?

I know of people who use it correctly, so what should I do? May it be that there is a wrong version of Pyglet uploaded on the website? Should I convert it with 2to3?

Comment: Which instructions did you follow? In other words, how exactly did you install it?

Comment: I followed the instruction that can be found here, http://www.pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/installing_using_setup_py.html. I even downloaded the official alpha doc, but the instructions were the same. I looked into _init_.py contained in the .zip I downloaded and the print there is actually WRONG, written in Py2 style instead of Py3, as said before. I should have said it before, i'm running OS X at the moment, and can't try on Windows or Linux, because I haven't got my other computer for now.

Comment: setup.py ought to run 2to3. You did run `pythonX.Y setup.py install` with a 3.x python?

Comment: Yes, I tried both with sudo and without sudo. I'm going to try passing setup.py to 2to3, thanks.

Comment: Huh? Passing `setup.py` to `2to3` to doesn't do anything (that matters). I meant that `setup.py install` will automatically run `2to3` on the entire pyglet source code, so the error you're seeing shouldn't appear. Which is what's baffling me. By the way, please double-check which version of pyglet you're using.

Comment: Oh yes, I misread, sorry. Well, I just redownloaded the .zip from here http://code.google.com/p/pyglet/downloads/detail?name=pyglet-1.2alpha1.zip&can=2&q=1.2alpha1. However, unpacking the zip and navigating to Pyglet and opening _ init _.py (without having ran the installer) I can see that the error is there, so I think that it is not related to the installer itself, but to the files that are already there.

Comment: (I'd take this to the chat but SO gives me an error, so:) Yes, the source code as-is doesn't work under Python 3, hence the need to run `2to3`, which `setup.py install` would do, without touching any 3.x-incompatible code. Something else must be afoul. Please try `python3 setup.py install` again, watch out for output from 2to3 (e.g. "skipping implicit fixer: ..." near the end). **Edit:** Nevermind, I just tries it myself (I usually install pyglet slightly differently, with `pip`) and it fails for me too. I'll investigate.

Comment: I'll just state that I too have run into this issue, the only python on this fresh install is 3.3. Same error 2to3 never got ran after running `python setup.py install`

Comment: I have the same issue with Python 3.3.2. 
Did anybody find a solution to this problem? Have I to downgrade to the 2.7 version?

Answer (score 6):

I have gotten Pyglet 1.2alpha1 to work on Windows 8 with Python 3.3.2.  (The method should be the same on linux, aside from the different folder paths)

The problem is that when you run `python setup.py install` it will seem to hang for a long time after you see the first few lines following `"skipping implicit fixer"`. If you then close the terminal/bash window (thus aborting the install process) and then run the setup.py again, it will skip 2to3 conversion and simply install the py2 source files.

The reason for the apparent "hang" is that it simply takes a while for 2to3 to convert the files, but if you wait long enough, the conversion will take place, and it will correctly convert and install the module.

If you have already installed this once, you will have to delete a few folders for the install to work properly.

First, delete the **build** folder in the 1.2alpha1 source folder: `%unzip_folder%\pyglet-1.2alpha1\build`
(where unzip_folder is the folder where you unzipped the Pyglet 1.2alpha1 source)

Also delete the **pyglet** folder from the python Lib: `%python%\Lib\site-packages\pyglet`
(where %python% is the python install folder, which defaults to  C:\Python33 on Windows)

Then run `python setup.py install`. It should go through all the steps (copying files to build, converting using 2to3, and finally byte-compiling to the Lib subfolder).

Comment: Thanks for this. It works. but now I am trying to build cocos2d for python 3.3. Have you done it?

Comment: This way didn't work for me :(, maybe because I am using windows 7?

Comment: This should work on Windows 7 as well, Llopis. What seems to be happening in your case?

Comment: +1 for the 'what happens when you're impatient and stop the install thinking it hung' portion.

Answer (score 1):

Pyglet 1.2 alpha is only "python3 ready" i.e. it won't run with python3 out-of-the-box but has to be converted via 2to3. (After the conversion it won't run with python2 anymore.)

To use pyglet with python2 and python3 projects I always copy pyglet into a subfolder of the project (and convert it with 2to3 if I want to use it with python3).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem: **Windows 8**, **Python 3.3.2** and **Pyglet 1.2alpha1**.
I look around a lot but until now no solutions found.

I installed the **2.7.5** Python version, changed the previous *Python.exe* file (the one of the 3.3.2 version) to *Python33.exe* and adjusted accordingly the PATH environment variables.
Then I installed Pyglet **1.1.4** (from command line, the executable has also more errors) in the 2.7 version.

I use Eclipse, so I have added both the Interpeter in the PyDev Settings. 
For now all works fine if I use the Python27 interpreter.